# Unable to assign date to date picker control using javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, datetimecontrol

I want to set the today's date to the DateTime control of sharepoint. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
    var today= mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;  
    $( "td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='DateTimeFieldDate']" ).val= today;   
});
```

But I am not getting the value inserted in the DateTime conrol's text box. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't set value like this

```
$("DateTimeControlID").val = "date";
```

you have to set value like this

```
$("DateTimeControlID").val("date");
```